# execution of chown(container files) get hung

Tags: docker, ubuntu, zalenium

I'm trying to run Zalenium docker on ubuntu 18.04. Below is my command.

```
curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dosel/t/i/p | bash -s start

or

docker run --rm -ti -p 4404:4444 -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v /home/emiteqa/eMite/videos:/home/seluser/videos --privileged dosel/zalenium start
```

I got stuck at "Copying files for Dashboard"

```
Docker binary already present, will use that one.
Docker version 18.09.0, build 4d60db4
-- LOG 07:33:35:233537096 Ensuring docker works...
-- LOG 07:33:35:414698248 Ensuring docker-selenium is available...
haveged: haveged starting up
Copying files for Dashboard...
```

After investigate, I find the cause is the zalenium get hung at below line in [zalenium.sh](https://github.com/zalando/zalenium/blob/master/scripts/zalenium.sh)

```
sudo chown -R ${HOST_UID}:${HOST_GID} /home/seluser
```

Then, I go into the zalenium container. I try to run sudo chown on any file in the container, it get stuck.

```
seluser@5ada56c01231:~$ ls -ltr
total 40396
-rwxrwxr-x 1 seluser root       41277 Nov 24 15:23 zalenium.sh
-rwxrw-r-- 1 seluser root       15086 Nov 24 15:23 zalando.ico
-rwxrwxr-x 1 seluser root         770 Nov 24 15:23 wait-testingbot.sh
-rwxrwxr-x 1 seluser root         983 Nov 24 15:23 wait-saucelabs.sh
-rwxrwxr-x 1 seluser root         933 Nov 24 15:23 wait-lambdatest.sh
-rwxrwxr-x 1 seluser root         746 Nov 24 15:23 wait-cbt.sh
-rwxrwxr-x 1 seluser root         831 Nov 24 15:23 wait-browserstack.sh
-rwxrwxr-x 1 seluser root        1268 Nov 24 15:23 start-testingbot.sh
-rwxrwxr-x 1 seluser root        2679 Nov 24 15:23 start-saucelabs.sh
-rwxrwxr-x 1 seluser root        1061 Nov 24 15:23 start-lambdatest.sh
-rwxrwxr-x 1 seluser root        1078 Nov 24 15:23 start-cbt.sh
-rwxrwxr-x 1 seluser root        1287 Nov 24 15:23 start-browserstack.sh
-rwxrw-r-- 1 seluser root        2699 Nov 24 15:23 logging_info.properties
-rwxrw-r-- 1 seluser root        2738 Nov 24 15:23 logging_debug.properties
-rwxrw-r-- 1 seluser root        1082 Nov 24 15:23 logback.xml
-rwxrw-r-- 1 seluser root        2128 Nov 24 15:23 LICENSE.md
-rwxrw-r-- 1 seluser root         637 Nov 24 15:23 error.html.bak
-rwxrw-r-- 1 seluser root       10996 Nov 24 15:23 dashboard_template.html
-rwxrw-r-- 1 seluser root        4529 Nov 24 15:23 Analytics.md
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root    root    41184199 Nov 24 15:23 zalenium-3.141.59v.jar
drwxrwxr-x 1 seluser root        4096 Nov 24 15:27 css
drwxrwxr-x 1 seluser root        4096 Nov 24 15:27 js
drwxrwxr-x 1 seluser root        4096 Nov 24 15:27 img
drwxrwxr-x 5 seluser seluser     4096 Dec  5 01:56 videos
-rwxrw-r-- 1 seluser seluser     3420 Dec  6 07:00 nginx.conf.bak
-rwxrw-r-- 1 seluser seluser     3404 Dec  6 07:00 nginx.conf
-rwxrw-r-- 1 seluser seluser      627 Dec  6 07:00 error.html
drwxr-xr-x 2 seluser seluser     4096 Dec  6 07:00 logs
-rw-r--r-- 1 seluser seluser     1181 Dec  6 07:00 docker_info.txt
seluser@5ada56c01231:~$ pwd
/home/seluser
seluser@5ada56c01231:~$ sudo chown seluser:seluser wait-testingbot.sh

^C^C
seluser@5ada56c01231:~$ ^C
seluser@5ada56c01231:~$ sudo chown seluser:seluser wait-testingbot.sh
seluser@5ada56c01231:~$ sudo chown seluser:seluser wait-saucelabs.sh
^C^C
seluser@5ada56c01231:~$ sudo chown seluser:seluser wait-saucelabs.sh
seluser@5ada56c01231:~$
```

What I have tried

- If I touch a new file and run sudo chown, there is no problem.
- If I CTRL+C and retry, it will pass.
- By using exact same steps starting from docker installation, I can run zalenium successfully on aws
  server.
- I googled, but didn't find any similar issue. I know it's possibly due to env issue, but I have no clue how to troubleshoot.

Thanks in advance for any suggestion and help.

Comment: What happens if you use root to start Zalenium? Could it be that the user does not have enough priviledges to start docker containers properly?

Comment: Hi, Diego, Thanks for the replay. It's still same problem. Any other suggestion?

Here are the groups I'm in.
    `qa@VMUBUNTU1804QA01:~$ groups
qa adm dialout cdrom floppy sudo audio dip video plugdev netdev lpadmin sambashare docker`

With root, still same problem.
    `root@VMUBUNTU1804QA01:/home/qa# curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dosel/t/i/p | bash -s start`

Comment: What happens if you try in an different machine? Different operating system?

Comment: ok. will try. thanks.